# PHP Contact Form not working

Tags: php, html

Below is the code for my PHP contact form. But when I submit it I get the following error:

" Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')' in F:\wamp\www\peter harris\form.php on line 12 "

I want to know what is wrong with my code. I am fairly a beginner.

Thanks

```
              <?php
        $subject = $_POST['Contact Form'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $event_location = $_POST['event-location'];
        $event_date = $_POST['event-date'];
        $event_time = $_POST['event-time'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $date = date(r);

        $list=array($name,$email,$phone,$event_location,$event_date,$event_time,$date);
        $strTo = "example@domain.com";
        $strSubject = " Contact Form -";
        $strFrom = trim($_POST["Contact Form - name"]);
        $str_content = "From". trim($_POST["name"]) . "\r\n" . "Email: " . trim($_POST["EMAIL"]) . "\r\n" . "Phone: " . trim($_POST["phone"]) . "\r\n" . 
        "Event Location: " . trim($_POST["event-location"]) . "\r\n" . "Event Date: " . trim($_POST["event-date"]) . "\r\n" .  "Event Time: " . trim($_POST["event-time"]) . "\r\n" .
        "Message: " . trim($_POST["message"]) . "\r\n" . "Date: " .      trim($_POST["date"]) . "\r\n" ;
                mail($strTo,$strFrom,$strSubject,$str_content); 

            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'></SCRIPT>");
             echo "<script>alert(' YOUR EMAIL HAS BEEN SENT. ')</script>";
              echo "<script>window.history.go(-1)</script>";        

  ?>
```

My HTML code for the FORM:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="form.php" method="post" 
    onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input id="name" type="name" name="name" value="NAME"  
     onfocus="if (this.value=='NAME') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') 
     this.value='NAME';"/><br />
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="EMAIL" onfocus="if     
    (this.value=='EMAIL') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') 
    this.value='EMAIL';" /><br />
<input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" value="PHONE" class="phone" onfocus="if 
    (this.value=='PHONE') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='')   
     this.value='PHONE';" /><br />
<input type="text" name="event-location" value="EVENT LOCATION" onfocus="if  
    (this.value=='EVENT LOCATION') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='')  
    this.value='EVENT LOCATION';" /><br />
<input type="text" name="event-date" value="EVENT DATE" onfocus="if  
    (this.value=='EVENT DATE') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='')  
     this.value='EVENT DATE';" /><br />
<input type="text" name="event-time" value="EVENT TIME" onfocus="if  
    (this.value=='EVENT TIME') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='')  
    this.value='EVENT TIME';" /><br />
<input type="text" name="message" value="MESSAGE" class="message" onfocus="if  
    (this.value=='MESSAGE') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='')  
     this.value='MESSAGE';" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

Comment: You could try pasting it into one of the online PHP syntax checkers:  http://www.hcibook.com/meandeviation/php-syntax-check/v5-2/syntax-check.php

Comment: Why is the last element in the array on a separate line? This isn't normally an issue in PHP, but are there hidden characters there or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the syntax errors, this is how your code "should look like":

```
<?php
// Trim all POST strings
$data = array_map(function($value){
    return is_string($value) ? trim($value) : $value;
}, $_POST);

$body = "From {$data['name']}\r\n".
    "Email: {$data['email']}\r\n".
    "Phone: {$data['phone']}\r\n". 
    "Event Location: {$data['event-location']}\r\n".
    "Event Date: {$data['event-date']}\r\n".
    "Event Time: {$data['event-time']}\r\n".
    "Message: {$data['message']}\r\n".
    "Date: {".date('r')."}\r\n";

mail('example@domain.com',$data['name'],'Contact', $body);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Your email has been sent.');
window.history.go(-1);
</script>
```

Few things you should know:

1. it's not really recommended to have query variable names with spaces
2. you should validate the data you're getting; if you've put some field in your form it doesn't mean you'll always get it at all (not to mention the right format)
3. there is practically no difference between `$something` and `$array['something']` so you don't need to define each array key you need to use as new variable
4. there is no need to have 3 script tags in order to have 2 function calls
5. try not to output HTML through PHP (and separate the presentation from logic altogether)

Comment: In line twelfth line... Event time there is an extra ")" after the '[event-time]")"}'... i removed that and dont get an error now.  But still changing the mail email to my email address i did not get an email. I am testing this on my local computer wamp server. Does this send the email?

Comment: @user1073972 Fixed, I didn't try my code. You probably don't have a mail server attached on your local machine, try with a live web server, it has to work :)

Answer (score 4):

`"\r\n" . ; "Event Time: "` you have a semi colon there that breaks the line.

ok I see some inconsistencies with the `$_POST['Variable']` calls.

```
$subject = $_POST['Contact Form- '];

$strFrom = trim($_POST["Contact Form - name"]);
```

Both of those $_POST variables do not exist in the form you are sending comment them out. and change $strFrom to = $name.

Comment: Good catch. Weird that codepad shows this error, but not the author's original one... http://codepad.org/Sv8EwgL6

Comment: @user1073972 is what you posted your raw code??? or just a snippet?? also im guessing the semi colon fix did not fix the problem?

Comment: I posted my complete PHP code... The semicol fix did not fix the problem. :(

Comment: Added the html code. Also that was a typo, but I dont think that mattered for the error.

Comment: The error I was getting was because of the extra ")". Check my comment on the below post. Now I'm not getting an error but I'm still not sure if it sends the email.

Comment: @user1073972 Well it wasnt really because of an expecting a "(" it was because of the fact that the $_POST variable didn't exist. So for this question I have answered it. So you may accept my answer. But the checking to see if the email is sent you should change the to to an actual email address(maybe your personal email). Also if you still are having trouble on the email you should open another question about it. GL.